# error when applying HPN-SSH patch on openssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I followed instructions in http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh

When i tried to apply HPN-SSH patch on openssh  on my ubuntu 12.10 i got the below error
At the end it asked me "File to patch" which i am not sure what to apply.

```
zcat /home/ubantu/openssh/openssh-6.1p1-       hpn13v14.diff.gz | patch
patching file auth2.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 49.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 71 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 216 (offset -13 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file auth2.c.rej
patching file buffer.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 125 (offset -2 lines).
patching file buffer.h
patching file channels.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 169 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 316 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 816 (offset -5 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 1812 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 1830 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 2190 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 2243 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 2273 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 2308 (offset -22 lines).  
Hunk #10 succeeded at 2738 (offset -22 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 2866 (offset -28 lines).
Hunk #12 succeeded at 3517 (offset -43 lines).
patching file channels.h
Hunk #1 succeeded at 126 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 166 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 245 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 306 (offset -1 lines).
patching file cipher.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 50 (offset -5 lines).  
Hunk #2 FAILED at 83.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 158 (offset -6 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 318 (offset -20 lines).  
Hunk #5 succeeded at 348 (offset -25 lines).
1 out of 5 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file cipher.c.rej
patching file cipher-ctr-mt.c
patching file clientloop.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1817 (offset -12 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1877 with fuzz 1 (offset -12 lines).
patching file compat.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 169 (offset -2 lines).
patching file compat.h
patching file kex.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 46 with fuzz 2 (offset -3 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 81 (offset -11 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 397 (offset -13 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 438 (offset -13 lines).
patching file kex.h
Hunk #1 succeeded at 135 (offset -3 lines).
can't find file to patch at input line 967
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff -NupwB canonical/Makefile.in kitchen/Makefile.in
|--- canonical/Makefile.in      2012-04-03 21:27:57.000000000 -0400
|+++ kitchen/Makefile.in        2012-11-07 16:57:24.000000000 -0500
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Answer (score 0):

Download a [pre-patched or precompiled copy of HPN-SSH](https://launchpad.net/~w-rouesnel/+archive/openssh-hpn) for Ubuntu. It's the path of least-resistance.